# Relation between topological entropy and metric entropy

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, entropy, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory

It is well known that, for a dynamical system $T$ on a metric space $(X,d)$, the variational principle connects the definition of metric entropy and topological entropy. In other words,
if
$$M(X,T) := \{ \mu\,\, \text{probability measure} : \mu= T_*\mu   \} $$
is the set of invariant measures for $T$, then

$$h_{top}(T)= \sup_{\mu \in M(X,T)} h_{\mu}(T) $$

where $h_{top}(T)$ is the topological entropy and  $h_{\mu}(T)$ is the metric entropy relative to $\mu$.

I have seen somewhere that, if we denote by $E(X,T) \subset M(X,T)$ the set of invariant ergodic measures for $T$, then

$$h_{top}(T)= \sup_{\mu \in E(X,T)} h_{\mu}(T) $$

My questions are: is this true? If it is true, how is it possible to prove it?

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed true that for the purposes of the variational principle one may take supremum over ergodic invariant probability measures (at least when $X$ is compact and $T$ is continuous, which are the standard assumptions for the variational principle). I present below (the outline of) an argument (from Walters' *An Introduction to Ergodic Theory*, p.190, which includes further details).

---

Let $X$ be compact metrizable, $T:X\to X$ be continuous. Recall that we have an ergodic decomposition

$$\Pi_\bullet: M(X;T)\to M(E(X;T))$$

where the codomain is the space of Borel probability measures on the space of $T$-invariant ergodic Borel probability measures on $X$. $\Pi_\bullet$ is determined completely by the formula

$$\forall \phi\in C^0(X;\mathbb{R}): \int_X \phi(x)\, d\mu(x)=\int_{E(X;T)}\left(\int_X \phi(x) \, d\epsilon(x)\right)\, d\,\Pi_\mu(\epsilon).$$

(Here $C^0(X;\mathbb{R})$ is the space of all continuous real valued functions on $X$.)

This formula is abbreviated as $\mu=\int_{E(X;T)} \epsilon\, d\, \Pi_\mu(\epsilon)$, or alternatively in probabilistic notation $\mathbb{E}_\mu=\mathbb{E}_{\Pi_\mu}(\epsilon\mapsto \mathbb{E}_\epsilon)$, where $\mathbb{E}_\nu$ means the expectation w/r/t the anonymous measure $\nu$.

**Theorem:** For any $\mu\in M(X;T)$:

$$\operatorname{ent}_\mu(T)= \int_{E(X;T)} \operatorname{ent}_\epsilon(T)\, d\, \Pi_\mu (\epsilon).$$

In words, the metric entropy of $T$ w/r/t $\mu$ is the average of the metric entropies of $T$ w/r/t $\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ runs over the ergodic components of $\mu$. This theorem is also proved in the aforementioned book (p. 186); the main idea is to prove it first for entropies w/r/t finite partitions and to use the upper-semicontinuity of entropy.

---

Let us denote the (extended) nonnegative number

$$\sup_{\mu\in M(X;T)} \operatorname{ent}_\mu(T) =:\operatorname{topent}(T)\in [0,\infty].$$

Like you cite of course by the variational principle this is really the topological entropy of $T$ and it has a separate definition that uses no measure theoretical structure whatsoever. So $\operatorname{topent}(T)$ is not only the top (metric) entropy, it's also the topological entropy. Though we don't need this for the corollary below which is what you are asking.

**Corollary (to the theorem above):** For any $\mu\in M(X;T)$:

$$\sup_{\mu\in M(X;T)} \operatorname{ent}_\mu(T)\stackrel{\tiny \text{def (for our purposes)}}{=}\operatorname{topent}(T)= \sup_{\mu\in E(X;T)} \operatorname{ent}_\mu(T).$$

**Proof:** Assume that $\operatorname{topent}(T)$ is finite. Let $\delta\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and take a $\mu\in M(X;T)$ such that

$$\operatorname{topent}(T)\geq \operatorname{ent}_{\mu}(T)> \operatorname{topent}(T)-\delta.$$

By the ergodic decomposition of $\mu$ and the theorem above we have that at least for one $\epsilon\in \operatorname{supp}(\Pi_\mu)\subseteq E(X;T)$

$$\operatorname{topent}(T)\geq \operatorname{ent}_{\epsilon}(T)> \operatorname{topent}(T)-\delta.$$

(Recall that $\Pi_\mu$ is a probability measure.)

The infinite entropy case is similar.